# Choosing stable video container and encoder

Tags: video, encoding, directshow, video-capture, directshow.net

I developed an application which records and displays a live video source (AVI: H264) using DirectShow. When I choose H264 as encoder and AVI as container, if I stop the graph; recorded video plays well. But if my application crashes; I can't play recorded video. I don't insist to use AVI or H264. What container and encoder do you suggest for recording a video which it's file is playable even application crashes while recording?

As you know most DVRs work this way. If you unplug a DVR, you can watch recorded video until last second before unplugging. How they store videos? What container/encoder they use for recording?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

MPEG-2 transport stream supports h264 and AAC content and has no index, so any portion should be playable.

Comment: So I can use h264 as video encoder and AAC as audio encoder. But which file container can I use? Is it possible to put MPEG-2 TS in AVI or MKV file? I think my file should be *.MPG. Am I right? Thank you for you answer :)

Comment: Typical extension for this would be MTS. That is what you get with a HDD/Flash-Drive-Recorder. You need a Mpeg2-TS mulitplexer filter to create such a file with DirectShow.